# How can I declare a variable to solve this in my temperature calculator?

Tags: javascript, variables, conditional-statements

I am currently trying to write code in Visual Studio Code to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit, and I have my prompts to ask the user what temperature they want to convert and which of the two they would like to convert.

I am stuck on how to declare the variable that displays the solution to my conversion formula. Here is what I have so far.

```
let userInput = prompt("would you like to convert to C or F?")

let userTemp = prompt("what temperature?")

console.log("30" == 30)
console.log(30 === 30)
console.log("" == 0)

toLower(c)
toLower(f)

let result = (userInput / 5 * 9) + 32

if (userInput == 'c') {

    (userTemp / 5 * 9) + 32 == result // <- Needs to ba a variable before you use it
}
else {

    (userTemp - 32) * 5 / 9 == result
}

document.write(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code. Although you do create a variable `result`, you're trying to convert a `c` or `f` to a number, you should be using `userTemp` here instead of `userInput`.

This is a moot point though as `(userTemp / 5 * 9) + 32 == result` is an equality check and results in a boolean (true/false) value.

You should instead assign `(userTemp / 5 * 9) + 32` to the variable `result`

```
result = (userTemp / 5 * 9) + 32;
```

So you need to not assign a value initially to `result` and assign the value inside the `if ... else`.

```js
let userInput = prompt("would you like to convert to c or f?")
let userTemp = prompt("what temperature?")

userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

let result;

if (userInput == 'c') {
  result = (userTemp - 32) * 5 / 9
} else {
  result = (userTemp * 9 / 5) + 32
}

document.write(result)
```

I've also swapped the calculations as converting 61 to c gave 141.8 instead of 16.1.